# Cannot get Query elements on razor page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, selection

I have two query-selection on my page one for customers and one for suppliers. Why do I not see any elements?

== c# code ==

[c# code of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHb6A.png)

[Pic of VS19 with debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18qtq.png)

in debugger elements are shown see pic number 2

== in Razor Page==

[Pic of HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip2FJ.png)

Unfortunately I cannot see any items. Any Ideas?

[Layout of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peQci.png)

Attached you get my code sorry for only posting pictures

My c# Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using WorkCollaboration.Data;
using WorkCollaboration.Models;

namespace WorkCollaboration.Pages.Contacts
{ 
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly WorkCollaboration.Data.WorkCollaborationContext _context;

        public CreateModel(WorkCollaboration.Data.WorkCollaborationContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            CustomerDropDownDisp = await _context.CustomerDropDown.ToListAsync();  // Added for DropDown
            SupplierDropDownDisp = await _context.SupplierDropDown.ToListAsync();  // Added for DropDown
            return Page();
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Contact Contact { get; set; }
        public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<CustomerDropDown> CustomerDropDownDisp { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SupplierDropDown> SupplierDropDownDisp { get; set; }

        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            _context.Contact.Add(Contact);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("/ContactsOverview/Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Here my Razor Page Html

```
@page 
@model WorkCollaboration.Pages.Contacts.CreateModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    ViewData["RandomId"] = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode();
}

<h1>Create</h1>
<h4>Contact</h4>
<p>
    <a asp-page="/ContactsOverview/Index">Back to Index</a>
</p>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Contact.ContactId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contact.ContactId" value='@ViewData["RandomId"]' readonly="readonly" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contact.ContactId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Contact.LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contact.LastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contact.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Contact.FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contact.FirstName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contact.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Contact.CustomerId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contact.CustomerId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contact.CustomerId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Contact.CustomerId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select id="CusId" aps-items="@(new SelectList(Model.CustomerDropDownDisp,"CusId","CusName"))">
                    <option value="" selected disabled> -- Select Customer--</option>>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Contact.CustomerId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Contact.SupplierId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contact.SupplierId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contact.SupplierId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Contact.SupplierId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select id="SupId" aps-items="@(new SelectList(Model.SupplierDropDownDisp,"SupId","SupName"))">
                    <option value="" selected disabled> -- Select Supplier--</option>>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Contact.SupplierId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Contact.PrivateStreet" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contact.PrivateStreet" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contact.PrivateStreet" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Contact.PrivateStreetNo" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contact.PrivateStreetNo" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contact.PrivateStreetNo" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Contact.PrivateStreetAdditionalInfo" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contact.PrivateStreetAdditionalInfo" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contact.PrivateStreetAdditionalInfo" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Contact.PrivateZip" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contact.PrivateZip" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contact.PrivateZip" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Contact.PrivateTown" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contact.PrivateTown" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contact.PrivateTown" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact.PrivateCountry, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-group" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Contact.PrivateCountry, new List<SelectListItem>
                    {
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "CH", Value = "CH", Selected = true },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "D", Value = "D" },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "FL", Value = "FL" },
                    }, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact.PrivateCountry, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Contact.PrivatePhone" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contact.PrivatePhone" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contact.PrivatePhone" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Contact.BusinessPhone" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contact.BusinessPhone" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contact.BusinessPhone" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Contact.MobilePhone" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contact.MobilePhone" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contact.MobilePhone" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Contact.Mail" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contact.Mail" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contact.Mail" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <select asp-for="DayOfWeek" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<DayOfWeek>()">
                <option value="">Choose a day</option>
            </select>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <a href="/ContactsOverview/Index" class="btn btn-primary">Back to List</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your post to include your code directly as text, instead of as a screenshot. Screenshots of code are difficult to read, reproduce, or search. Posts that rely on screenshots of code will usually be closed, if not deleted, which reduces your changes of getting an answer. (I've voted to close this question, but will happily retract my vote once you've edited your question.)

Comment: Aside, in your debugger screenshot, you're showing results for the `SupplierDropDownDisp`, but the highlighted code all pertains to the `CustomerDropDownDisp`. Are you seeing results for the supplier drop down? Are you _sure_ the debugger is showing data in the `CustomerDropDownDisp`? I ask because the screenshot doesn't demonstrate that—though it doesn't contradict it either.

Comment: Please set breakpoint to check if CustomerDropDownDisp contain data in it and please share the code instead of screenshot when asking question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put breakpoint on the line which set data for `CustomerDropDownDisp`.This must caused by your database do not have data.You could follow the steps below to check.

Set breakpoint and press IIS Express to debut the project:
[image]

You could see if the database does not contain any data for `CustomerDropDownDisp`,the `count=0` and the razor does not display element:

[image]

And if it contains data for `CustomerDropDownDisp`,the selectlist could render successfully:

[image]

Comment: You asked me to post the code and now you rejected it twice... 

In the mean time I found the problem was in the Razor Page (Old Code) So how can I post code if I can not use edit? Comments are too short

Comment: I guess I need to make a new request for the problems or? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi @ChristofOberholzer,you need edit your question instead of edit my answer to share your detailed code.And no need to make a new request if it still the same issue.

Comment: And did you check if the `CustomerDropDownDisp` has data like my answer did?